# Filename code formatting

Tags: feature-request, markdown, code

I suggest to enhance the code formatting with an optional argument for a filename.

===test.tex===

```
\documentclass{}
\begin{}
\end{}
```

Nice workaround suggested in comments to use 3 #:

#### test.tex

```
\documentclass{}
\begin{}
\end{}
```

Comment: The code formatting is provided by the stackexchange team for all stackexchange sites and we mods do not have direct access to it. You could use `### test.tex` to create an headline 3rd order for the filename.

Comment: See [Markdown help](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for all the ins-and-outs on markdown available on the Stack Exchange network. Specifically for headers, see [Headers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#headers). Click on 'show more' (and possibly 'expand all') to see more.

Answer (score 7):

In most cases, the specific name of a file doesn't matter, but even if it does, there's no need for a heading outside of the code. If the file name does matter, there usually are several files involved with one main file accessing the other(s) (e.g. a .bib file). In those cases, I'd recommend using a `filecontents` environment in order to enable user to create everything with one file. If you complement that with the `\jobname` macro, which carries the current file's name, you enable users here to have maximal influence on the names of files while still being able to refer to files. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{one,
    author = {Anthony Apple},
    title = {Title}}
@book{two,
    author = {Barbara Banana and Chris Coconut},
    title = {Title}}
@book{three,
    author = {Donna Date and Eric Eggplant and Fred Fig},
    title = {Title}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You can also do things like `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-hello-world.tex}`. Here is some more information about the `filecontents` environment and the [`filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) (which might be handy in some cases), quoted from the [`filecontents` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/filecontents):

> > The environment `filecontents` is intended for passing the contents of
> >     packages, options, or other files along with a document in a single
> >     file. It has one argument, which is the name of the file to create.
> >     If that file already exists (maybe only in the current directory if
> >     the OS supports a notion of a `current directory' or`default
> >     directory') then nothing happens (except for an information message)
> >     and the body of the environment is bypassed. Otherwise, the body of
> >     the environment is written verbatim to the file name given as the
> >     first argument, together with some comments about how it was
> >     produced. The environment is allowed only before `\documentclass` to
> >     ensure that all packages or options necessary for this particular run
> >     are present when needed. The begin and end tags should each be on a
> >     line by itself. There is also a star-form; this does not write extra
> >     comments into the file.
>
> (The
>   comment about `filecontents` being valid only before `\documentclass` is,
>   in fact, untrue. `filecontents` is allowed anywhere in the document's
>   preamble.)
>
> The `filecontents` package provides a hacked-up version of the
>   `filecontents` and `filecontents*` environments that lifts the two
>   restrictions stated above, namely that existing files are never
>   overwritten and that `filecontents` must be used before the
>   `\documentclass` declaration (really, the `\begin{document}`). `filecontents` is therefore a more convenient way to write external files from
>   within a LaTeX document than is provided by default by the LaTeX2ε
>   kernel.